# Advantage of Func<T> in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking Func method in C# i am not sure what is the advantage over normal methods.

Func Method

```
Func<int, int, int, long> multiply = delegate(int a, int b, int c) { return a * b * c; };
Console.WriteLine(multiply(2, 3, 4));
```

normal method

```
long multiply (int a , int b , int c)
{
 return a*b*c;
}
```

can any one explain?

Comment: a delegate can be set / accessed / manipulated from outside the class that declares it. a normal method cannot.

Comment: You can change the value of the delegate to whatever else you want at runtime. That's not possible with the method.

Comment: You probably want to promote one of the inputs to long in the multiply too - I'm not a guru on this stuff but I'd expect that to do multiplication as ints and then promote the result to a long rather than multiply as longs which would actually allow the result to be bigger than an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Func<>` is a multi-purpose delegate, which means its a sort of "pointer" to a function instead of a function itself.

One advantage is that this pointer can be pased as an argument to another function

Very contrived example:

```
public double Execute(Func<double,double,double> theFunction, double lhs, double rhs)
{
    return theFunction(lhs,rhs);
}

var add = new Func<double,double,double>( (x,y) => x + y);
var addResult = Execute(add, 1.1, 2.2);
var multiply = new Func<double,double,double>( (x,y) => x * y);
var multiplyResult = Execute(multiply, 1.1, 2.2);
```

Comment: private static string[] Name(Func<string, bool> filter)
    {
    string[] name= new string[]
        { "Tom", "Harry", "Cherry","joe" };
    return name.Where(filter).ToArray();
    }   < br/> string[] shortName = Name(n => n.Length < 4);
foreach (string name in shortName)
    Console.WriteLine(name); Will return "Tom" and "joe"

Comment: What havs either of those comments got to do with my answer?

Comment: @Jamiec nothing , just found something , thought useful to share.

Answer (score 6):

Delegates are used when you want to use arbitrary methods, but still fulfill a signature. A good example are the LINQ methods, like `Where`:

```
Where<T>(Func<T, bool> condition)
```

For the method, it does not matter what exactly `condition` is.

Any method (or lambda expression) with the signature:

```
bool Condition<T>(T argument)
```

can be used in place of condition. The last type parameter for `Func<>` specifies the return type. If you want a delegate with `void` as return type, use `Action<>`.

Comment: should not the `Condition` function be in same case?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: in `bool Condition<T>(T argument)`, Condition function is in title case where as the other is in lower case.

Comment: The lower case one is a method argument, while the upper case one specifies a method signature. In C#, methods are capitalized, while arguments to methods are lower case.

Answer (score 2):

`Func` defines a function's type. Because you can declare the type and variables of the type, you can pass functions to other functions as arguments.

```
 public void Compute( Func<int, int, int> function, int x, int y )
 {
     return function( x, y );
 }

 public int multiply( int x, int y )
 {
     return x*y;
 }

  ...

 Compute( multiply, 2, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Func<int, int, int, long> multiply = delegate(int a, int b, int c) {
     return a * b * c;
};

Console.WriteLine(multiply(2, 3, 4))
```

;

is  an inline functions  which  means the  following advantage:

- Thread  safe
- fast than the  call to the  normal  method

Comment: finally someone who explains it very simply! kudos

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Func<>` as other function arguments. You can have a gui control that takes a function as a parameter and draws it on the plane.

```
public void DrawFunction(Func<double, double> func)

(...)

DrawFunction(Math.Sin)
```